# WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, cordova, websocket

I'm trying to connect to a web socket server, I get an error

> WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)

Added a description of CSP

```html
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
      default-src *  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
      script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
      connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
      img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
      frame-src * data: blob: ;
      style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
      font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
      ">
```

Added a description to the .plist file

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

In safari, everything works correctly, but in the simulator there is still an error.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I entered the wss server address incorrectly